# Connect to MySQL Database using sockets

Tags: mysql, flutter, sockets, dart

I am following up from my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64163529/best-way-to-keep-fetching-new-data-from-mysql), where I was suggested to use sockets for a real time chat application using MySQL database. I have been researching some information about the usage of sockets in flutter, after trying several times and several different codes and failing, I clicked inside [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51077233/using-socket-in-flutter-apps) about sockets and found out this code snippet:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

Socket socket;

void main() {
   Socket.connect("localhost", 4567).then((Socket sock) {
   socket = sock;
   socket.listen(dataHandler, 
      onError: errorHandler, 
      onDone: doneHandler, 
      cancelOnError: false);
   }).catchError((AsyncError e) {
      print("Unable to connect: $e");
   });
   //Connect standard in to the socket 
   stdin.listen((data) => socket.write(new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim() + '\n'));
}

void dataHandler(data){
   print(new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim());
}

void errorHandler(error, StackTrace trace){
   print(error);
}

void doneHandler(){
   socket.destroy();
}
```

I may be wrong but I think this may be the way to connect to my database, if it is not please help me out, I would appreciate it. But I can't find a way to write in the database name, username and password in order to access the data from a specific MySQL database.